# Sql syntax working in MS Access, but not in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my first time posting so I'm sorry if I make any mistakes.
So I have a database in access and I am trying to get the top 10 Client ID, the number of reservations made by the client and the sum of those reservations.
I have this Sql code in MS Access and it works there, but when I enter it in Visual Basic, I get te following error.
SQL syntax:

```
SELECT top 10 Clienti.CodCl, sum(Rezervari.SumaTotala) ,
count(Rezervari.CodRezervare)  
FROM Clienti 
INNER JOIN Rezervari ON (Clienti.CodCl = Rezervari.CodCl) 
  where datarezervarii BETWEEN  #6/21/2020#  AND  #6/23/2020# 
  group by Clienti.CodCl 
  order by sum(Rezervari.SumaTotala) desc
```

The result table in access

[image]

Visual basic error :

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The SELECT statement includes a
> reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or
> the punctuation is incorrect.'

Thank you.

Comment: Replace the `SUM` expression in your `ORDER BY`. Use `ORDER BY 2` instead, where the `2` means *the second column in the SELECT*. Does that fix things?

Comment: "when I enter it in Visual Basic" - exactly how are you doing that?

Comment: Edit question to show VBA code.

Comment: Error message appears to be VB.Net (distinctly different from VBA). Please tag and describe appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. For anyone looking for the same answer, this is the code that i have used:

```
Dim top1 As String
    top1 = "SELECT top 10 Clienti.CodCl, sum(Rezervari.SumaTotala) as suma, count(Rezervari.CodRezervare) FROM
    Clienti INNER JOIN Rezervari ON Clienti.CodCl = Rezervari.CodCl where rezervari.datarezervarii BETWEEN  #" & Inceput & "#  AND  #" & Sfarsit & "# group by Clienti.CodCl order by sum(Rezervari.SumaTotala) desc"
    Dim cmdtop1 As New OleDbCommand(top1, con)
    Dim dstop1 As New DataSet
    Dim datop1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtop1)
    datop1.Fill(dstop1, "Clienti INNER JOIN Rezervari ON Clienti.CodCl = Rezervari.CodCl")

    Dim readtop1 As OleDbDataReader
    readtop1 = cmdtop1.ExecuteReader
    readtop1.Read()
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Give an Alias to the aggregated fields. It's likely that .NET do not call them "Expr1001" and if inthe code you are referring to them you get the error.